# How to install tensorflow on python

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, gpu

I wanna install tensorflow. I used these commands in anoconda prompt:

```
1- conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5 
2- activate tensorflow
```

the next step is the below command but doesn't work:

```
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

The response is:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It would be appreciated if anybody help me.

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify `pip` in your initial install command.  I think `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5` should install it automatically along with several other packages.

Comment: Do you have python 3.5 installed? Open a command prompt and type `python` and if you get no errors then you have it installed

Comment: The `conda create` is just making an environment, you still do need to install tensorflow via `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. Your problem is with anaconda and pip though, the environment you just created should have updated the paths so that pip is on the path, I don't see why that hasn't happened. @Ben10 had a good question there.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Anaconda on Windows 7 and installed Tensorflow this way:

in the start-menu start cmd.exe, then copy the path to your Anaconda-Installation (where Python.exe lies) with ctrl-c. In cmd-window write cd (change directory) and paste the Anaconda-path with the right mouse button, press enter. Now that youre in the Anaconda-path you write:
python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow